# "apt-cache rdepends --installed" Indicates That a Package Has Been Loaded Twice!

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

**Debian Stretch; apt 1.4.11**

```
$ apt-cache rdepends --installed libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
Reverse Depends:
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
```

Any idea why the `libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37` package is showing up twice here? I get similar results from **Aptitude**:

```
  --\ Packages which depend on libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 (12)
    --\ Depends (12)
p     gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0 1.10.4-1
p     gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0 1.10.4-1
p     gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0 1.10.4-1+deb9u
p     gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0 1.10.4-1+deb9u
p     gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad 1.10.4-1+deb9u2
p     gstreamer1.0-vaapi 1.10.4-1+b1
p     gstreamer1.0-vaapi 1.10.4-1+b1
p     libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev 1.10.4-1+
i A   libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 2.18.6-1~deb9u1
i A   libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 2.18.6-1~deb9u1
p     libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 2.18.6-1~deb9u1
p     libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 2.18.6-1~deb9u1
```

FYI, the equivalent **Aptitude** command line query does *not* exhibit the same behavior:

```
$ aptitude search ~Dlibgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
p   gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0                                             - GObject introspection data for the GStreamer libraries from the "bad" set        
p   gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad                                               - GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set                                             
p   gstreamer1.0-vaapi                                                     - VA-API plugins for GStreamer                                                     
p   libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev                                        - GStreamer development files for libraries from the "bad" set                     
i A libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37                                                   - Web content engine library for GTK+                                              
p   libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2                                              - Web content engine library for GTK+ - GTK+2 plugin process
```

While I've found several references to an **apt** bug (one [here](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/commit/c74d1ee6dc7e7139f243cd57e258f51b3677d59c)), I've seen nothing that specifically mentions what I am seeing.

Any ideas as to what is causing duplicate packages references to appear?
.

**UPDATE AFTER MULLING OVER** EduardoTrápani's **EXCELLENT ANSWER (BELOW):**

```
$ apt list -a libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
Listing... Done
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0/oldoldstable,now 1.10.4-1+deb9u2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0/oldoldstable 1.10.4-1 amd64
```

Also:

```
$ apt rdepends --installed libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
Reverse Depends:
  Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (<< 1.10.5)
  Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 1.10.4)
```

Since my installed version of **libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0** is **1.10.4-1+deb9u2**, it satisfies BOTH version conditions stated in the output of said `apt rdepends --installed libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0` command. Perhaps that is why **Aptitude** reported said package twice (above).

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: @EduardoTrápani **Aptitude** is a GUI app and I'm unable to block copy text from it...

Comment: That's just a front-end, you could run `aptitude` from the command line, just like you ran `apt-cache` for example.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Yes, I did something similar while researching the subject question - I'll add that info to my post...

Comment: To copy from `aptitude`, hold down the Shift key while you click and drag.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yay!

Comment: @StephenKitt Shift-click-drag works to send the selected text to the clipboard - how do I save same to the copy buffer?

Comment: Shift-Ctrl-C in most terminals.

Comment: @StephenKitt Well, that just causes **Aptitude** to crash. I tried it in both **xterm** and **xfce4-terminal**!

Comment: @Digger right, you need a terminal which supports explicit copying; xterm doesn’t, I don’t know about the Xfce terminal. You don’t actually need to copy; after selecting with Shift, you can middle-click elsewhere to paste the selected text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132716/discussion-between-digger-and-stephen-kitt).

Comment: FYI, I was able to determine that **xfce4-terminal** *DOES* support explicit copying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default this command

```
$ apt-cache rdepends --installed libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
```

will list all the types of dependencies. That means that a package that specifies both a `Depends` and `Breaks` will be listed twice.

You might be able to avoid that by asking `apt-cache` to list only the `--important` dependencies. The man page states that that's equivalent to: `--no-pre-depends`, `--no-depends`, `--no-recommends`, `--no-suggests`,
`--no-conflicts`, `--no-breaks`, `--no-replaces`, `--no-enhances`. But if the package has more than one `--important` dependency on a single package, that package will still be listed more than once.

```
$ apt-cache rdepends --installed --important libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
```

My recommendation though is to use the much simpler and better suited for human use:

```
apt rdepends --installed libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
```

That will tell you exactly why each package is there, with version numbers and all.

Comment: I find `aptitude why` to be even more useful than `--installed` ;-).

Comment: Eduardo, `apt-cache rdepends --installed --important libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0` outputs the `libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37` package twice. `apt rdepends --installed libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0` yields `Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (<< 1.10.5)` and `Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 1.10.4)`. FYI, `apt list libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37` yields `libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37/oldoldstable,now 2.18.6-1~deb9u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
`

Comment: Ah, that's because there are two independent `Depends` entries. `--important` does not remove duplicates, it removes the listed categories of dependencies. If there are multiple entries belonging to `--important' they will be still listed multiple times. I fixed the answer.

Comment: sounds like `apt-cache rdepends` needs to get fixed to remove showing duplicates